# Odd prime divisors of $X^2+DY^2$ is again in same form

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Is there any common proof which works for all $D\in \{1,2,3\}$ of the following fact mentioned below which is purely elementary?

Let $D\in \{1,2,3\}$. Then any odd prime divisor of $ X^2+ D Y^2$ where $(X,Y)=1$ is again in the same form.

Can we apply some sort of induction to prove this?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to stipulate $p\nmid X,Y$?  otherwise, for example, $3|3^2+3^2$, but $3\ne x^2+y^2$

Comment: Please see the edit

Answer (score 2):

Given Tanner's stipulation, that the prime does not divide either of $x,y,$ the conjecture follows from class number one.

If Legendre symbol $(-4D|q) = -1,$ it is not possible to have
$$ x^2 + D y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q $$
unless both $x,y \equiv 0 \pmod q.$

Special treatment is need for primes dividing $4D.$

If  Legendre symbol $(-4D|p) = 1,$ it follows that $p$ is integrally represented by a (reduced) form of that discriminant. For your values of $D,$ the only (reduced) form is the one you named.

You begin to get failures of this, but still well behaved, at class number two. At discriminant $-20,$ the form $2x^2 + 2xy + 3 y^2$ represents primes $7,23$ that are not represented by the principal form $x^2 + 5 y^2.$  But    $$ 9^2 + 5 \cdot 4^2 = 161 = 7 \cdot 23 $$

Comment: maybe this is obvious, but just so I understand, when you say class number, are you speaking of the class number of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt D)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner that is the right question. I am talking about the form class number, primitive (positive) binary quadratic forms. For positive forms, this equals the ideal class number. The matter is dealt with in Henri Cohen, A course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory, section 5.2 is called Ideal and Quadratic Forms.   My favorite is Binary Quadratic Forms by Duncan Buell.  I wrote up all of it for the blog on this site, later they deleted the blog

Comment: Thanks, @Will, $+1$